# Where can find the full version of Dragon Ball Super's sixth ending?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I am aware that the name of it is "Chachan Music" but when I look it up I can never find the full version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full song legally you can buy the cd here :
http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/VICL-37235

Or you can buy only this song on Itunes : https://itunes.apple.com/fr/album/chaofan-music-ep/id1173386575